# PDF download in blank

Tags: web-services, http, pdf

In my WebService, I have a service that should download a PDF file for the client (GET Http request) but it comes all blank.

My Controller:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(nomeArquivo);

ByteArrayOutputStream pdfBA = termoService.readFully(is);

httpServletResponse.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, Constants.HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_PDF);
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"termo-adesao.pdf\"");
httpServletResponse.setContentLength(pdfBA.size());

OutputStream os = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
pdfBA.writeTo(os);
os.flush();
```

MyService.readFully:

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream readFully(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1){
        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return baos;
}
```

I saw some tutorials in the internet but somehow everytime I get the file, it opens with the same number of pages as the original but it is all blank (The letters are missing, not white). In stackoverflow I saw some issues alike, but all related with JSF.

Comment: Have you saved the pdf with empty pages as file and compared it to the original?

Comment: Yes, the URL give me a PDF file, but when I open, it's blank, doesn't matter if it is on Chrome, Adobe Reader or Mozilla.

Comment: And what are the differences?

Comment: Oh, I see now. I'll check byte from byte and let you know.